# LogCat from background thread not working in Android

Tags: android, logging, buffer, logcat, flush

I have a background thread (it's an AsyncTask) that is logging to LogCat using `Log`, but the logging isn't showing up in LogCat. Is there any reason that this might be?

My suspicion is that the task might be returning before the buffer is flushed. If that's the case, is there any way to force `Log` to flush its buffers?

Thanks!

Comment: I also faced this problem in eclipse. Simple eclipse "Restart" solved my problem.

Comment: Could you post logging code? Also, are you sure you have the correct level set (info, debug, error) for viewing the log in Eclipse?